# SpringBoot mockMVC test internationalization not work

Tags: spring-boot, testing, internationalization

I'm trying to apply spring internationalization in my project.

I'm using AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.

When testing one Test with accept-header, it works properly
But when testing multiple Tests, it doesn't work

**This is my test code**

```
@Test
void test1() {

  ...

  builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/path")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .locale(Locale.ENGLISH)
        .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request));

  ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(builder);

  //then
  resultActions
       .andDo(print());
}

@Test
void test2() {

  ...

  builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/path")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .locale(Locale.KOREA)
        .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request));

  ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(builder);

  //then
  resultActions
       .andDo(print());
}
```

**Environment**

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver acceptHeaderLocaleResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(Locale.KOREA));
    return acceptHeaderLocaleResolver;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    rs.setBasename("messages");
    rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    return rs;
}
```

when testing test2, it print messages which translated in korean

but when testing test1 and test2 in same time
test2 print message which not translated in korean.

I can't find reason why it works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get Message From enum which initiated by MessageSource.
It didn't work.

I change my logic to use MessageSource directly and it works